# blurred image from AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, uikit, avfoundation, ios7

I am developing a iOS7 video recording application. The camera screen in our application requires to show a blurred backgound similar to the one shown in iOS7 control Center. While the video preview is being shown, we need to show the blurred control center.
As suggested in WWDC video 226, I have used the code provided below to get camera preview snapshot and then applying blur and setting this blurred image to my view.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_camerapreview.frame.size, NULL, 0);

[_camerapreview drawViewHierarchyInRect:rect];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

lightImage = [newImage applyLightEffect]
```

Here _camerapreview is a UIView which contains AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer. The *newImage obtained from the context is for some reason black.

However if i use [_camerapreview snapshotView] returns me a UIview with previewlayer content. But there is no way to apply blur on UIview.

How can I get a blurred image from the camera preview layer?

Comment: Be advised that iOS 7 is still under NDA. For iOS 7-specific questions, ask in the Apple Developer forums.

Comment: Since we're past the NDA, did you ever make any progress on this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you put your overlay onto the video preview itself as a composited video layer, and add a blur filter to that. (Check the WWDC AVFoundation sessions and the AVSimpleEditoriOS sample code for compositing images onto video) That way you're staying on the GPU instead of doing readbacks from GPU->CPU, which is slow. Then drop your overlay's UI elements on top of the video preview within a clear background UIView.

That should provide greater performance. As good as Apple? Well, they are using some private stuff developers don't yet have access to...

Comment: The question is not about video preview or video player layer. The question is about about video CAPTURE e.g. camera layer.

Comment: @poGUIst I think you're mistaken in the terminology -- the question concerns compositing the video preview layer of the camera with a blurred background. But if you have a better answer, I suggest you submit it instead of just doing a drive-by downvote on an answer from last year.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting Apple from this [Technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1817/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014134):

> A: Starting from iOS 7, the UIView class provides a method
>   -drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:, which lets you render a snapshot of the complete view hierarchy as visible onscreen into a
>   bitmap context. On iOS 6 and earlier, how to capture a view's drawing
>   contents depends on the underlying drawing technique. This new method
>   -drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates: enables you to capture the contents of the receiver view and its subviews to an image
>   regardless of the drawing techniques (for example UIKit, Quartz,
>   OpenGL ES, SpriteKit, AV Foundation, etc) in which the views are
>   rendered

In my experience regarding AVFoundation is not like that, if you use that method on view that host a preview layer you will only obtain the content of the view without the image of the preview layer. Using the  `-snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:` will return a UIView that host a special layer. If you try to make an image from that view you won't see nothing.

The only solution I know are `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`. Each one has its own limit. The first one can't work simultaneously with a `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` acquisition, the latter makes the shutter noice.